# Vue: html height incorrect

Tags: html, css

After switching pages several times, I get this bug where in chrome or firefox thinks that the page is taller than it actually is. I am using vue-router currently.

[image]

I don't know if it makes any difference but here is my css rule for the body:

```css
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: html {height: 100%} body{ height: 100%}

Comment: @user120242 unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: This type of bug is virtually impossible to debug without a [mcve]. Try creating one using codesandbox.io or any other multi-file node based online editor.

Comment: A possible cause for this behavior is navigating from a taller page to a shorter one after scrolling down in the tall one past the height of the short one. This is a common problem of SPA's and has different solutions. You could always scroll to top on router navigation. Or you could at least check if the current scrollTop + viewport height do not exceed current page height. If they do, scroll up to the point where it doesn't. (Or to top, if that's what you think should happen).